# How to extend material-ui component style to another react component from differently library?

Tags: material-ui

For example:

```
import { CssBaseline, ThemeProvider, Typography } from "@material-ui/core"; // MUI **Typography** component
import { Text, RichText } from "@some-library/core"; // some-library's **Text** component

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    typography: {
      h1: {
        fontFamily: Garamond,
        fontSize: pxToRem(56),
        lineHeight: pxToRem(64),
        letterSpacing: pxToRem(-0.5),
        [breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
          fontSize: pxToRem(72),
          lineHeight: pxToRem(76)
        },
        [breakpoints.up("md")]: {
          fontSize: pxToRem(104),
          lineHeight: pxToRem(112)
        },
        [breakpoints.up("lg")]: {
          fontSize: pxToRem(120),
          lineHeight: pxToRem(128),
          letterSpacing: pxToRem(-0.75)
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />

      <Typography variant="h1">MUI Typography Heading</Typography>

      <Text tag="h1">Library B text component</Text>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

All I want is to apply the same styles of the `<Typography>` for the `<Text>` component.

I know can I can add className to the other component like `<Text className={"MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-h1"} tag="h1"`>. Is that the right approach? And if I do like this would the props of  components also be used in the  component? Like `<Text variant="h2">` and would it take all the responsiveness of Typography too?

Can the styles of MUI component be extended to another react component with all the other functionality (props etc) using any other way?

[image]

I am trying to create a shared (**MUI components + some-library components**) component library and using MUI as the base library for components and styles. And I have created custom theme for the MUI components but not able to extend these styles to the components of another library which too has few basic components (text field, buttons, form elements etc).

Please let know if the question makes sense as I am very new to react and MUI. Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, for what I know, the answer should be no: you cannot extend material-ui component style to another component from different library. Because a component from another library would not accepts the same Material UI props (in your example, `variant="h1"` would be not recognized as valid props in other component except Material UI components).

Of course, as you said, you could assign the same Material UI class to another component and that component will follow the same style:

```
<Text className={"MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-h1"} tag="h1"> // this work
```

Or you could extend a Material UI component. Suppose that you want to make your own `Text`, you could extend `Typography` component using `withStyles` like:

```
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
const MyText = withStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    color: "green"  // in this case, MyText will have a green text color 
  }
}))((props) => <Typography {...props} />);
```

But, as you can see, I extended a `Typography` component, not a component coming from another library. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-responsive-typography-updated-forked-g42rm?file=/demo.js) a codesandbox example.

As I said, this is what I know. Maybe there is a way to achieve what you asked (even if I have some doubts because how to map Material UI props to be accepted by another component that has different props?)